# Controlling Voltage

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, amperage

I'm seeking help in finding a way to control the incoming voltage for custom LED fixtures.  My fixtures use 12V 3014 240/M LED strips with 221 resistors.  The strips are wired in a parallel circuit (please see attached pics).  People that "get it" understand that 110V to 12V converters are necessary.  There is a very large market that will not run converters; fire / rescue is one example.  These systems use batteries with outputs that range from 13.5-15.2 volts.  (And they wonder why my fixture gets hot!)
Could you please help me discover a way; either in the parallel circuit or in between the fixture and the power supply to control the voltage my fixture receives?
The strips I use have the following specs:
12V 3014 240led / M
10 watts / ft.
73 led / ft.
730 lumen / ft
.61 amps / ft

Thank you for reading my email and I anxiously await your response and am open to any / all suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Use larger resistors.

Comment: Knowing the oprating voltage and the current this fixture consumes, you can calculate series resistor to place inbetween the power supply and LEDs, R=U/I.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a low-dropout regulator between your input supply and your LED strip.

You can use a linear regulator, like LM2940-12, but this may dissipate too much power. You can work out the power dissipated in a linear regulator by multiplying the worst case voltage drop (Here it is 15.2 - 12V) by the current (0.61A per foot). The LM2940 is 1Watt, so you could power at most 1/2 foot (0.3A x 3.2v = 0.96W ).

If you need to power longer lengths, you should use a switching regulator. LT8610 will give you 2.5A with high efficiency. That would be enough to power 4 foot of your LED strip at 0.61 A / foot.

Comment: I'm not sure if you noticed the username, but this is not the end user. They don't get to decide how it is installed.

Comment: Hi Ignacio - I missed the user name, but did see the OP asked "Could you please help me discover a way; either in the parallel circuit or in between the fixture and the power supply to control the voltage my fixture receives" - This method fits in between the fixture and the power supply.

Comment: Exactly, this strips will work down to 10 V with reduced brightness. A switching reg is exactly whats needed, and can be installed between the power and fixture, or retrofitted inside.

Comment: First and foremost, thanks to all of you that have taken the time to respond and help with my issues.  
The more I read the more I realize how much I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

The specs I provided are a per strip spec.  My larger fixture uses 5 strips per fixture; ie, 50watts and 3.05amps per foot. Would multiple regulators be necessary?  Does the regulation change fore and aft of the regulator?  I am currently searching for the dimensions of this device as I'm afraid that I will run into fitment issues underneath the diffuser.  I was recently pitched this as a solution:  http://www.vicorpower.com/dc-dc-converters-board-mount/high-density-dc-dc-converters?pml_grid_row_1_col1_values=12&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filterNum=2&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filter1=product.i18nAttribute1%3D%2728+%289-36%29%27&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filter2=&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filter3=&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filter4=&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filter5=&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filter6=&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filter7=&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filter8=&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filter9=&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filter10=&pml_grid_row_1_col1_filterReset=0#matrix
Never mind an additional $200 per fixture (under 4')!  If this is my only solution; I'm toast.

I will continue to search and learn; thank you again and I look forward to your input.

Comment: This looks like about right for an off-the-shelf switching power supply. Your alternative is to have someone design a regulator for you, but this will take time to get a reliable 200Watt supply built.

Comment: Hi, For an off the shelf 200W switching supply, this sounds reasonable for small quantity. If you search, I think you should be able to find something similar in quantity for $100.

Comment: Another alternative might work. If you use Resistors to drop 2.5V from your input supply. at 15.2V, your voltage would be 12.7V. At 13.5, it would be 11V. These would be need to be high power, 50 Watts for your 5 strips x 4' Fixture, but would be low cost and easy to build. You just need to divide the voltage drop (2.5V) by the current (Here 12.2A for 4') to get the resistor value (0.2 Ohms). A 50Watt 0.2Ohm resistor would be hard to find, but you could source 5x 1 Ohm 10 Watt resistors & wire these in parallel. How do your lights work between 11 and 12.7V.

Comment: Harry, thanks a bunch.  
While lumens drop a bit when under 12V, the temps between 11 and 12.7 are optimum.  
I've been testing this:  http://www.onsemi.cn/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=NSI45015W

Comment: They are used in place of the resistors on the strip.  The test was both a success and a failure.  Success because the temps were lower on the IC strips (integrated circuit), but also a failure because they were still too high.

I need a solution that prevents the input voltage from being more than 12.5